# Powershell syntax problem trying to write a non-expanded string with variables, but have Powershell expand and use string variables

Tags: powershell

I'd like to call this from another program, similar to calling it from the cmd prompt. I'd like to write it as is, like an unexpanded string to be called when an alert is triggered, but have it run inside a powershell runspace (when the alert is triggered) and expand the variable for $date, $date is always empty with what I've tried so far syntactically.

What is wrong with my syntax?

```
$omsaCommand = "omconfig system alertaction event=tempwarn execappath=`"Powershell.exe -NonInteractive -command `"$date = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString(); Set-Content -Path 'c:\omsaInfo\inventoryResults\temp.txt' -Value '$alertShortName - $date';`"`" ";
    
Invoke-Expression $omsaCommand;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping dollar signs in PowerShell path is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452401/escaping-dollar-signs-in-powershell-path-is-not-working): "*Instead of messing around with escaping dollar signs, use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`. It prevents PowerShell expanding `$` into a variable.*"

Comment: Not unless I couldn't get the combination correct, as I tried various combinations of single and double quotes before posting, without success

Comment: I can't speak for the outer `omsa` part, but for the inner PowerShell part, I guess it is something like this: ``$omsaCommand = "omconfig system alertaction event=tempwarn execappath=`"Powershell.exe -NonInteractive -command '$date = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString(); Set-Content -Path c:\omsaInfo\inventoryResults\temp.txt -Value $alertShortName - $date'`" "``

Answer (score 0):

For this, I couldn't find a syntax that allowed some variables to be compressed, others to be uncompressed, and fit within the framework of the parent application. The work around I came up with was to call

> execappath=`"Powershell.exe -NonInteractive -file C:\omsaInfo\createAlertFile.ps1 -alertName $alertShortName` "

which would allow me to run multiple commands without worrying about variable management