# Two variables in one string but only interpret one - PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, variables

I'm trying to do an API call in PowerShell.
The problem is that the call contains a "$" and PowerShell interprets that as a variable, and it also contains a real variable
it looks something like this:

[image: >$apicall = @'http://example.org/bar()?$format=json&filter=id eq $foo']

Is there a way how I can make it so $format is not interpreted, but $foo is?

(I need the "" around $foo)

I already solved this by just splitting it up into two string and then adding them together, but this seems very unstable to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping dollar signs in PowerShell path is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452401/escaping-dollar-signs-in-powershell-path-is-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend construct your uri from multiple parts:

```
# define base uri
$baseUri = "http://foo.example/bar()"

# define individual query parameters
$queryParameters = [ordered]@{
    '$format' = 'json'
    'filter' = 'id eq "{0}"' -f $foo
}

# concatenate query parameters
$paramString = $queryParameters.GetEnumerator().ForEach({ 
    $_.Key,$_.Value -join '=' 
}) -join '&'

# construct full URL from base + parameter string
$apicall = $baseUri,$paramString -join '?'
```

The `'` single-quotes around `$format` will prevent any attempt at variable expansion.

The literal `"`'s are preserved in the filter string by also using `'` to define a string formatting template, but then using the `-f` operator (which will expand `$foo` before applying).

This approach obviously requires more source code, but it makes it easier to maintain the URI parameters.

---

If everything but the `$foo` value is static, you can also use an expandable here-string literal (`@"` instead of `@'`) with a `$` character, simply escape it using a backtick:

```
$apicall = @"
http://foo.example/bar()?`$format=json&filter=id eq "$foo"
"@
```

Comment: So there is no way of doing this without some kind of constructing a string?

Comment: @Lumberjack Sure, I've updated the answer