# How to copy files from one computer to multiple in a LAN PowerShell

Tags: powershell, lan

I must copy multiple files from one computer to many on a LAN.

I tried to create a script but it doesn't work.
Could you please help me to view where the problem is :)

```
$computers='pc1','pc2','pc3','pc4'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock {
    foreach ($computer in $computers) {
        Copy-Item -Path '\\$computer\c$\temp\' -Destination '\\pc5\c$\temp\'  -Recurse
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of things jump out.  For example, `$computers` is not going to be defined in your scriptblock as it's running on a different computer (look at [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.3#using-local-variables)), and you are likely to have the [double-hop issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.3) as you are remoting to another machine, then trying to access yet another machine.

Comment: You are having issues with single quotes, backslashes, and dollar signs.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452401/escaping-dollar-signs-in-powershell-path-is-not-working.  I recommend building the path in pieces to get around issues.  $Path = $computer  $Path += '\c$\temp' Copy-Item -Path $Path -Destination '\\pc5\c$\temp\'  -Recurse  Do same for destination.