# Ansible - Error when trying to stop a windows service with "$" in it

Tags: error-handling, ansible, windows-services, special-characters, ansible-module

**How to stop Windows services with special characters using Ansible `win_service` module?**

I am facing an error when I try to stop SQL Server services using `win_service` module when the service has `$` in it like:

```
SQLAgent$SQL01
SQLAgent$SQL02
MSSQL$SSQLS01
MSSQL$SSQLS02
```

This is my playbook:

```yaml
- name: Get MSSSQL Services
  ansible.windows.win_service_info:
    name: "MSSQL*"
  register: mssql_info

- name: Set MSSQL services
  set_fact:
    mssql_services: "{{ mssql_info.services | selectattr('state', '==', 'started') | map(attribute='name') | list | replace('$', '%24') }}"

- name: Get SQL Agent Services
  ansible.windows.win_service_info:
    name: "SQLA*"
  register: sqla_info

- name: Set Agent services
  set_fact:
    sqla_services: "{{ sqla_info.services | selectattr('state', '==', 'started') | map(attribute='name') | list | replace('$', '%24') }}"

- name: Stop SQL services
  win_service: 
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: "stopped"
  loop:
    - "{{ sqla_services }}"
    - "{{ mssql_services }}"
  register: stop_output
  ignore_errors: yes

- debug:
    msg: "{{ stop_output }}"
```

The error it gives me is:

```json
{
  "exception": "The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: System.Object[]\r\nAt line:282 char:5\r\n+     Get-Service -Name $Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue\r\n+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Service], WildcardPatternException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand\r\n\r\nScriptStackTrace:\r\nat Get-ServiceFromName, <No file>: line 282\r\nat <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 952\r\n\r\nSystem.Management.Automation.WildcardPatternException: The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: System.Object[]\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.WildcardPatternParser.Parse(WildcardPattern pattern, WildcardPatternParser parser)\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.WildcardPatternMatcher.MyWildcardPatternParser.Parse(WildcardPattern pattern, CharacterNormalizer characterNormalizer)\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.WildcardPatternMatcher..ctor(WildcardPattern wildcardPattern)\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.WildcardPattern.Init()\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.WildcardPattern.IsMatch(String input)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MultipleServiceCommandBase.MatchingServicesByServiceName()\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MultipleServiceCommandBase.MatchingServices()\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand.ProcessRecord()\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()",
  "msg": "Unhandled exception while executing module: The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: System.Object[]",
  "_ansible_no_log": null,
  "changed": false,
  "item": [],
  "ansible_loop_var": "item",
  "_ansible_item_label": []
}
```

Is there a way to stop this kind of services using Ansible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At least in the past there was an [Ansible Issue #37621 - "_`win_service`: does not work with special chars_"](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/37621) ...

Comment: Have you tried escaping it? Here would be some escapes flavours I would try `SQLAgent\$SQL01`; `SQLAgent\\$SQL01`; `SQLAgent\\\$SQL01`; `SQLAgent$$SQL01`. The repetition of backslashes up to three are because ```\``` do have a certain meaning in Python and YAML, so you could want to escape the special meaning of that character so it reach the actual command Ansible will run on the Windows node.

Comment: Oh and probably also `SQLAgent\`$SQL01` based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452401/escaping-dollar-signs-in-powershell-path-is-not-working

Comment: How can I add the "`" before "$"? I get the name of the SQL service interactively by running win_service_info. The first thing I tried is to change the character "$" to its ASCI form but also is not working.

Comment: I still have the problem, any udea how to solve it?